# Wrappers for ATL containers so they can be used with std:: container templates?

Tags: c++, atl

Are there any "wrappers" for ATL containers like CSimpleArray, so that they can be used with std templates that work with containers?

For instance, I was considering creating a CSimpleArraySTD template, which would take a CSimpleArray reference in the constructor, and then provide some of the standard calls. i.e. begin(), end(), empty(), size().... Then you could have code like:

CSimpleArray myClassArray;

for(auto &item: CSimpleArraySTD(myClassArray))
{
}

Same for CSimpleMap.

We have a bunch of code which uses ATL containers, but would like to be able to use them with modern C++.

Comment: Anyone want to comment on why this is got downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

Most standard C++ algorithms operate on iterator ranges.  `CSimpleArray` does not have C++ iterators, however raw pointers to array elements are valid iterators, and `CSimpleArray` does provide direct access to its elements, so you can create suitable pointers for standard C++ algorithms to use for iteration, eg:

```cpp
CSimpleArray arr;
...
someStdAlg(arr.GetData() + index, arr.GetData() + index + count);
// ie: someStdAlg(arr.GetData(), arr.GetData() + arr.GetSize());
```

Or:

```cpp
CSimpleArray arr;
...
someStdAlg(&arr[index], &arr[index + count]);
// ie: someStdAlg(&arr[0], &arr[arr.GetSize()]);
```

Comment: That sort of works for CSimpleArray, but was hoping that there was someone made wrappers for some of these templates, like CSimpleArraySTD<T>, which would take a reference to a CSimpleArray<T> and add functions like begin, end, empty, push_back, etc.

That way you could use statements like:
for(auto &item: CSimpleArraySTD(mySimpleArray))
{
}

Comment: @bpeikes what is stopping you from making your own wrapper? What you are asking for is trivial to make

Comment: Because it's another codebase to manage. There are tons of containers, and I'd have to test all of them. It's not completely trivial to do correctly. I also assumed that there might be a project out there that already did the work. A project like that would have more eyes on it too, which means less likely to have bugs.

Maybe I should create an open source library for this though.